# How to read-in a file that has a dictionary of dictionaries into a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a txt file whose contents is like this:

```
experiment_setup = {
        "1": {
            "FileName": "WT_L-1C.raw",
            "Condition": "Exponential",
            "Biorep": 1,
            "Fraction": "Cytoplasm",
            "Techrep": 1,
        },
        "2": {
            "FileName": "WT_L-1M.raw",
            "Condition": "Exponential",
            "Biorep": 1,
            "Fraction": "Membrane",
            "Techrep": 1,
        }
}
```

Ideally I would like to read that file into very similar dictionary of dictionaries. But currently the code I have looks like this:

```
param_file = sys.argv[2]
    
    # read param file as dictionary

    param_dict = {}

    file = open(param_file, 'r')
    for line in file.readlines():
        key, value = line.strip().split(":")
        param_dict[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    file.close()
```

basically what I enter in the form of `"a" : "b"` and puts it into a dictionary. How do do read in that experimental setup dictionary of dictionaries files in a dictionary of dictionaries

Comment: So your file just contains python source code? Why don't you just import it as a module?

Comment: this just looks like a configuration file, why don't you just use a standard format, like JSON or YAML? Or again, if it is just pyhton source code, just import it as a module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could open file file and read its entire contents. Then search for the first occurrence of a left-brace. Use ast.literal_eval to interpret the contents.

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.txt') as data:
    content = data.read()
    if (offset := content.find('{')) >= 0:
        param_dict = literal_eval(content[offset:])
        print(param_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'1': {'FileName': 'WT_L-1C.raw', 'Condition': 'Exponential', 'Biorep': 1, 'Fraction': 'Cytoplasm', 'Techrep': 1}, '2': {'FileName': 'WT_L-1M.raw', 'Condition': 'Exponential', 'Biorep': 1, 'Fraction': 'Membrane', 'Techrep': 1}}
```